# Difference between Option_Group and Option_Name in Register_Settings

Tags: options, settings-api, user-registration

I think the title pretty much says it all! I'm working my way through various tutorials on how to add an options page to my test plugin and am struggling to understand the `Register_Settings` function.

Every tutorial I have found quotes the codex for the arguments then uses the same text in the `Option_Group` and `Option_Name` argument. Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The codex defines the function as:

```
register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $option_validate_function );
```

- `$option_group` is settings group name. Use when displaying on a settings page for example
- `$option_name` is the database entry name
- `$option_validate_function` is the callback for this database entry/this option.

Most codex tutorials use an array of data in one `$option_name` but that's not required (just more efficient in terms of table rows). You can add multiple options with unique names under the same option group.

**Usage**

- `$option_name` is the name you access when using `get_option( $option_name )`.
- `$option_group` is the group name used when creating security with `settings_fields( $option_group )`.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly each `Option_Name` is a new line in the database, and they are held together by the `Option_Group`. But given that all of the tutorials use an array to store their data (and I understand the benefits of that) the two variables can be the same without any side effects. I really appreciate your help with this - its been bugging me for a few days!

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. That's the reason why tutorials use the SAME identifier for `name` as for `group`. The thing is, you don't NEED to. You may always register multiple `name` for a single `group`. Can be convenient if you have optional modules with separate save code. Saving might overwrite options already there. So you register a new option. But displaying them should happen at the same options page, so you tie it to the same group and voila.