# When should I use register_setting() and add_settings_field()

Tags: settings-api

When the time comes that one wants to create a settings page, one stumbles upon two semantically similar WP functions called:

- [register_setting()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/)
- [add_settings_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_field/)

I read the docs and am confused about those. Do I need both if I want to create a Settings Page in the WP Admin > Settings area?

**The first one says**:

> "Registers a setting and its data."

But register it for what? It uses `$option_group` which does not appear anywhere in the database, but seems to be used to create a nonce for a group of settings under the same hood, as I understand from [this WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81713/difference-between-option-group-and-option-name-in-register-settings).

It seems logic to think that it's enough to use `add_settings_field()`:

> "Add a new field to a section of a settings page."

But then again, what's the purpose of previously using `register_setting()`?

**Did I try something?**

Yes, I followed multiple examples using online references, but am still confused about what each function really does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems logic to think that it's enough to use `add_settings_field()`

Yes, it seems so, but it's really not enough:

- `register_setting()` whitelists the database option for a specific setting which then allows the option to be *saved and updated automatically* on the `wp-admin/options.php` page.

  Note that by "option", I'm referring to the second parameter for `register_setting()`.
- `add_settings_field()` on the other hand "reserves a space" in a specific [settings section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_section/) whereby in that reserved space, you're expected to output the HTML for your settings field (which could use one or more database options).

So `add_settings_field()` and `register_setting()` are not interchangeable (`add_settings_field()` does not automatically whitelist an option and `register_setting()` does not automatically reserve the above-mentioned space), and you need to whitelist options used in your settings field or form.

For example, if it had `<input name="foo_option" ...>`, then the `foo_option` would need to be whitelisted like so: `register_setting( 'my_settings_group', 'foo_option' )`.

And actually, the `add_settings_field()` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_field/#more-information) emphasized that:

> **You MUST register any options** used by this function with [register_setting()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) or they won’t be saved and updated automatically.

And you could also see about the same warning on the [Settings API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/settings/#adding-setting-fields)..

### Additional Notes

Another purpose of `register_setting()` is to make a setting be available in the [Site Settings (REST) API endpoint at `/wp/v2/settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/), with or without actually creating any settings page.

So for example, you would do like so to make `bar_option` available in the Site Settings API:

```php
register_setting( 'some_settings_group', 'bar_option', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'type'         => 'number',
    'default'      => 123,
) );
```

Comment: What would happen if you leave `$option_group` as an empty string? That parameter has always caused me a lot of confusion and I still don't really understand what is it meant to be.

Comment: @GerardReches well I guess it would only be left ungrouped... i.e. it would still be registered, but not placed in any group/category. I wouldn't do that, but it's up to you to decide on whether you should do so.. ✌